# What do the following exponential QQ plots tell me about the distribution of sample data?

Tags: statistics

[image]

I have two samples and these are their QQ exponential plots with line y=x through the origin overlayed. I am trying to deduce what the distributions of the two samples are. Do these suggest they have an exponential distribution as they follow the line? What does it mean when the second one tails off? thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If the QQ theoretical distribution you are plotting is exponential, then based on the QQ plots alone I would say your variable follows exponential distribution. If you are looking for a more formal test to demonstrate this, I would suggest taking the $\ln$ of your variable and using a Shapiro-Wilk Test of Normality. If the p-value is $<.05$, it would suggest taking that your data does not follow an exponential distribution. Here is a link to a good article from [SPSS](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/testing-for-normality-using-spss-statistics.php)
that describes the interpretation of the Shapiro-Wilk Test, as well as some other useful information.